# Find largest number in an array by picking k elements

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Given an input array of n elements with values from 0-9 and a value k, can you pick k elements to form the largest number such the index of the k elements in the array is in increasing order.

E.g.

```
Input [1,4,5,9,1], k = 2. Output - 91
Input [1, 2, 1, 6, 9], k = 3. Output - 269
```

Comment: sure, I can. But SO is not a coding-service, so please post what you've tried so far and where the problem with your approach is.

Answer (score 0):

You do understand that any n digit number is bigger then any (n-1) number (at least in usual number convention). So if you dont have 0s you need to find largest digit in first N-(k-1) and add it as a next significant digit to your number. It will be the place from which you start in the next iteration.
With 0s though you need to find workaround(some head brain usage still required).

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding this correctly, that you're forming the largest number possible as long as all the digits are ascending, wouldn't the solution simply be to:

1. Sort the array.
2. Move to element [n-k],
3. concatenate remaining numbers.

eg:

> Input [1, 2, 1, 6, 9], k = 3.

1. Sort Array: [1,1,2,6,9]
2. Move to [n-k]: [1,1,(2),6,9]
3. trim and concat: 269